# CoC's Sanity-like rules for the nWoD?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, house-rules, call-of-cthulhu, morality-system

Is there a good adaptation of Call of Cthulhu's Sanity rules to the Storytelling system of the new World of Darkness (possibly replacing Morality)?

(Edited the title to make it more precise.)

Comment: Are you primarily looking for a substitute Morality where the triggers for Degeneration are tied to exposure to the unnatural? Or do you really want an alternate-hit-point track like BRPs Sanity Point system?

Comment: I'd be interested in any available options but would prefer the first kind, I think. (Am considering adopting such a house rule, if there's a good one available.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Forbidden Lore" system from **World of Darkness: Mirrors** (p.28-32) is cognate to the Sanity system; characters garner Insanity points and lose rating in their Reason score. Along the way, they acquire Mental and Social penalties and gain bonuses to Occult endeavors — including the ability to use supernatural powers without gaining the associated template. The correspondences seem fairly close.

Answer (score 5):

To my mind, **CoC Sanity rules** are quite easy to use *as is*. For instance you can use the `sum` of the `mental` characteristics as a base and multiply by 5 or 6 (depending on how *crazy* your world is)  to get the starting `sanity` and then use the typical CoC Sanity rules.

I think something like that may work.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd have a look at [Unknown Armies mechanics](http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?428027-Unknown-Armies-Insanity-system), which to me look more nuanced (and I believe can be retooled for different game systems, too).

Comment: +13  Oh yes, they are very good indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The integrity rules from the [God-Machine Chronicle Rules Update](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/114078/World-of-Darkness-GodMachine-Rules-Update) could be a good substitute for CoC sanity.

Unlike the previous morality system that is based purely on sins (which the developers for GMC often refer to as a Victorian concept) , this system is based on breaking points,  and seeing cosmic horrors is a perfect example of that.

If you fail (and you can choose to fail dramatically) you can suffer a Condition (also in the GMCRU) that represents your sanity/integrity suffering.